# Error 1054 unknown column in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, dml

when I execute the `INSERT INTO account values(110,1250);` statement on the following table

```
+--------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| acc_no | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| amount | bigint(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I get this error

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'amount' in 'field list'

what can be the cause of it?

Trigger code is

```
create trigger demo before insert on account 
for each row 
set @diff=@diff+amount;
```

As I am learning triggers so I used a basic trigger defination

Comment: Is there any trigger on the operation?

Comment: What happens when you explicitely mention the field names in your insert command, like `INSERT INTO account (acc_no,amount) values(110,1250);`? Is `account` really the table name of the table structure shown?

Comment: yes, there is a before insert trigger after which this is causing the error.

Comment: For this statement INSERT INTO account (acc_no,amount) values(110,1250); the same error occurs

Comment: "Is there any trigger on the operation?" "yes, there is a before insert trigger after which this is causing the error."   show us the trigger code then?

Comment: Are you sure your column name doesn't contain whitespace or hidden characters?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct database? maybe you have the table account duplicated without a amount column.

Comment: Yes I am using the correct database  and column name is too correct and the trigger code I have edited in the code part

Comment: can you also provide the create statement table off the table amount?

Comment: create table account (acc_no int, amount int);

Comment: It worked when I dropped the table but when I created again it again showed me the same error..any hint regarding this..??

Answer (score 0):

You have to put code like this:

```
INSERT INTO account values('110', '1250');
```

If you select varchar in mysql then it should be string. if you select INT in mysql then no need put ''.